# change the version in GDataXML

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4, gdataxml

When I generate the XML using GDataXML by following this tutorial 
http://www.raywenderlich.com/725/xml-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-read-and-write-xml-documents-with-gdataxml 
and saved that to documents folder. 
After opening that file from documents folder, it has xml version = "1.0".
I want to change the  xml version to 2.0. Please give any suggestions to change the version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the tutorial, you have this, right?

```
GDataXMLDocument *document = [[[GDataXMLDocument alloc] 
        initWithRootElement:partyElement] autorelease];
```

To change the version of the xml document from "1.0" to "2.0", you can do this:

```
NSString *versionString = @"2.0";
const unsigned char *cVersionString = (const unsigned char*)[versionString cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
document.rootElement.XMLNode->doc->version = cVersionString;
```